# How to find which dynamic objects taking excessively long time to finish?

Tags: debugging, dynamic, wolfram-mathematica

M 8.0.1, windows 7.

A debugging question.

Sometimes when I start M and open my notebook (which has dynamics enabled in it before I closed it) I get this message

[image]

The problem is, no matter if I click on wait, or disable dynamics, the message keeps coming back.

I have to terminate the process itself (i.e. Mathematica) from windows task manager to get out of this.

Clearly I seem to have a bug somewhere in dynamics in my code.

My question is: Is there a way for M to tell me which dynamic objects is causing this problem? And any idea why telling it to disable dynamics updating is not helping here (as I keep getting the message).

thanks

Comment: Could you possible give us a simplified version of the notebook you're working on that's causing this issue? Dynamic evaluation can be a bit tricky, and it's hard to tell what's causing the issue without seeing code.

Comment: @Mike, I wish I can give you a simplified one. But this is a demo with tasking running in it, Event handler, and many dynamics, refresh all over the place. But I found out that if I keep hitting 'continue waiting' for much longer than I was doing (2-3 minutes) it will actually come back. Before I clicked couple of times and gave up. So, it is a timing issue. I seem to have some dynamic bug in my code. I spend more time debugging dynamics in Mathematica code than the time I take to add new code :) I wonder if Workbench can help in debugging dyanmics code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have some luck by evaluating:

`SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintKernelDynamicTraffic -> True]`

This will cause the Mathematica FrontEnd to print messages to the system console (on Mac, I don't know where it goes on Windows) whenever it sends Dynamic evaluations to the kernel.  If you can find the last Dynamic evaluation to print out when the message appears, that should be the one which is taking a long time to evaluate.

You'll probably want to disable this when you're done debugging so it doesn't fill your system log with millions of debug messages.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above, but did not seem to do anything. Is this documented somewhere? I googled it and do not see it mentioned any where. I am using V 8.0.1

Comment: WHat I mean in the above, is that I did not see any new message go to console or to the notebook. I could have been doing something, but not that I can see.

Comment: @Nasser this does send messages to the system console (that is, on OS X you can find the messages in /private/var/log/system.log). I don't know what the equivalent is on windows systems.

Comment: I see. I thought by 'system console' was meant the Mathematica console (i.e. Windows->Messages). I am not sure where the OS console is on windows either now. Will look for it. Thanks.

Comment: @nasser This is not a documented feature.  It appears in the "Undocumented" category of the Option Inspector, which you can get to by holding down the option/alt key when choosing Format > Option Inspector... from the menubar.

Answer (score 4):

You may find [DebugTrace](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/debugtrace/debugtrace.html), written by David Bailey, useful. It is a debugger which may also be used to debug dynamic constructions. In this documentation there is an example on how to debug such programs. Basically you set a breakpoint in your code, run it, and after it's done you are presented with detailed information on what happened when.

In general I highly recommend giving it a try, not only for the dynamic functionality.

Comment: +1, thanks, I downloaded this package and will use it. I did find my dynamics bug, was in initialization code in my demo. Only took 10 hrs to find ;). wish Mathematica has better diagnostic and debugging tools build-in. Any one knows if one can one use workbench to debug Manipulate based code and other Dynamic code?

Comment: @Nasser - Just guessing... If you are running a notebook launched via Workbench, the previous advice to SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintKernelDynamicTraffic -> True] will (probably...) print the dynamic info to the console within Workbench.